# Вычисление производной

Tags: java, алгоритм

Для алгоритма требуется найти производную. Не подскажете, какой библиотекой или каким-то иным способом можно это сделать? В скриншоте первый шаг. Заранее спасибо! [image: Алгоритм]

Comment: Mathcad не помог?

Comment: Мне требуется, чтобы алгоритм весь просчитывался автоматически. А если использовать Mathcad, то придётся делать паузы и так-же вводить полученые функции. Но это если я вас правильно понял.

Answer (score 1):

Это задача по численным методам - поиск минимума функции многих переменных методом градиентного спуска. Производную нужно вычислять **не аналитически, а программно** - делать маленький шаг dx<sub>i</sub> в каждом из направлений (по x<sub>i</sub>), и по определению производной найти частную производную по этой переменной.

```
δF(x1,x2...)/δxi = (F(x1,x2..xi + dxi...xn) - F(x1,x2..xi..xn)) / dxi
```

Набор частных производных образует вектор - градиент, направленный (в хорошем случае) в сторону минимума (возможно - локального)